# When $(\sum_{i=1}^nk_i < \prod_{i=n}^ni^{k_i}k_i!)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic, summation

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{N}$ a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $\phi: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ an enumeration of $\Omega$ such that $\phi(\omega)=i$ and $|\Omega|=n$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i < \prod_{i=1}^n(i^{\omega_i}(\omega_i!)),
$$ 
where $\omega_i \in \Omega$ and $i=\phi(\omega_i)$.

For which $\Omega$ is the statement true?

Comment: The lower bound for the index in the summation and the product is different each time (considering both title and the body of the question). Please be clear which one you mean. Also $I$ does not occur in the formulae.

Comment: Im guessing you don't want $i=0$ as the lower index on the product, since this will make the product either $0$ or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[König theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29) seems to be enough.